# Manipulating post data after sending System > Configuration form in Magento

Tags: magento

In Magento i've got a tab with a form in the Backend System > Configuration section with 2 input fields. 
I'd like to manipulate the data from those two fields before their saved. Is that possible?
And if so, whats the cleanest way to do that.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types of jobs are the purpose of "backend models". If a field has a backend_model configured, that backend model's `_beforeSave()` method will be invoked prior to the value being entered into the database.

See `Mage/Paygate/etc/system.xml` & search for `<backend_model>`
See `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Encrypted::_beforeSave()`

Comment: Thanks for the great awnser, don't think i would have solved it on my own. Thanks again!